# How to transit the heading below the ImageButton

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I need to make simple transition, so when I need to hover the `ImageButton` in css, the heading transition below the `ImageButton`.

```css
.ImageButton {
                opacity: .6;
                transition: opacity .6s ease-out;
                -moz-transition: opacity .6s ease-out;
                -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
                -o-transition: opacity .6s ease-out;
        }

        .ImageButton:hover{

            opacity: 3;
        }
```

```html
                   <td>
                      <h2> text</h2>
                      <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" cssclass = 
                     "ImageButton" runat="server" Height="91px" 
                      ImageUrl="~/images/cd.png" Width="93px" />
                  </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the text below it. I'm a beginner so don't necessarily believe me.

Comment: I want to hide the heading, once we hover to image , the heading transition bellow tha imge.

Comment: @torjek If you don't think that you have correct answers please try to add a comment below the question.